# django connec mysql --_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2006, <NULL>)

Tags: python, mysql, django

In fact, I learn the django from the website:https://docs.djangoproject.com/zh-hans/2.1/intro/tutorial02/

The next is my settting.py

```
DATABASES = {
    # 'default': {
    #     'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    #     'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    # }
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'django_01',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '9940',
        'HOST': 'localhost',   # Or an IP Address that your DB is hosted on
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
```

mysql :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SS3nx.png)

I want to know how to solve this problem,or I don't know what's the problem?
Thank you very much!

I think DATABASES is right, 
I want to connect mysql to django program named mysite, but I run 'python manage.py migrate':

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x0000000003B31D08>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Tools\Anaconda3\envs\test-django\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 216, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "D:\Tools\Anaconda3\envs\test-django\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 194, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "D:\Tools\Anaconda3\envs\test-django\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 227, in get_new_connection
    return Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "D:\Tools\Anaconda3\envs\test-django\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\__init__.py", line 85, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Tools\Anaconda3\envs\test-django\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 208, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2006, <NULL>)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Tools\Anaconda3\envs\test-django\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Tools\Anaconda3\envs\test-django\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 120, in inner_run
    self.check_migrations()
  File "D:\Tools\Anaconda3\envs\test-django\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 442, in check_migrations
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS])
  File "D:\Tools\Anaconda3\envs\test-django\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 18, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "D:\Tools\Anaconda3\envs\test-django\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 49, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "D:\Tools\Anaconda3\envs\test-django\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 212, in build_graph
    self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "D:\Tools\Anaconda3\envs\test-django\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 61, in applied_migrations
    if self.has_table():
  File "D:\Tools\Anaconda3\envs\test-django\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 44, in has_table
    return self.Migration._meta.db_table in self.connection.introspection.table_names(self.connection.cursor())
  File "D:\Tools\Anaconda3\envs\test-django\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 255, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "D:\Tools\Anaconda3\envs\test-django\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 232, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "D:\Tools\Anaconda3\envs\test-django\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 216, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "D:\Tools\Anaconda3\envs\test-django\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "D:\Tools\Anaconda3\envs\test-django\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 216, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "D:\Tools\Anaconda3\envs\test-django\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 194, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "D:\Tools\Anaconda3\envs\test-django\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 227, in get_new_connection
    return Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "D:\Tools\Anaconda3\envs\test-django\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\__init__.py", line 85, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Tools\Anaconda3\envs\test-django\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 208, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2006, <NULL>)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's because django can't support the new password encryption of mysql. You should try changing it.
You can do this from the mysql command line client:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I got the same `OperationalError: (2006, <NULL>)` when using python to connect to MySQL Server on Windows. It seems like the error has something to do with the new authentication method in MySQL 8. I reconfigured the MySQL server from using the recommended authentication method to "Use Legacy Authentication Method" and the error goes away.

[image]