# Cannot run migration command for django

Tags: python, mysql, django

I'm trying to practice and learn django to create a webapp and when I run the "python manage.py migrate" command, I get this error "django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)")". What is the possible cause and how can it be fixed?

Comment: Check your database user in settings.py

Comment: @Selcuk I have and still get the same error. In the manage.py I see an importation error for "django.core.management". could that be the issue and how can I solve it?

Comment: You checked and saw what? Then changed what? What is the import error? Post any details you have.

Comment: That the password stated was not the actual password and changed it to the right password. In the manage.py file, there is a prompt of unresolved import "django.core.management"

Comment: maybe your are giving wring password or you dont have grant pemission to the user on database

Comment: @YugandhaeChaudhari I have entered the right password, how can i have the grant permission to the user on database?

Comment: try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55955549/10872199), when i first used mysql with django I had similar error.